# Finding the heat flow across the curved surface of a cylinder #2

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-modeling, vector-fields, surface-integrals

This question is the second part to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2378641/356308) on the same problem.

I have the following problem:

> The temperature at a point in a cylinder of radius $a$ and height $h$, and made of material with conductivity $k$, is inversely proportional to the distance from the centre of the cylinder. Find the heat flow across the curved surface of the cylinder.

**The solution is as follows:**

Use cylindrical coordinates with the cylinder centred at the origin. Now

$T = \dfrac{\alpha}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$ where $\alpha$ is a constant

and hence

$\mathbf{F} = \dfrac{\alpha k(x, y, z)}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}$

$= \dfrac{\alpha k(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z)}{(r^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}$

The solution then says that the normal vector is $\mathbf{n} = (a\cos(\theta), a\sin(\theta), 0)$.

Finally, the solution says that the heat flux on the curved surface $r = a$ is

$\int^{h/2}_{z = -h/2} \int^{2\pi}_{\theta = 0} \mathbf{F} \mid_{r = a} \cdot \mathbf{n} d\theta dz$

$= \int^{h/2}_{z = -h/2} \int^{2\pi}_{\theta = 0} \dfrac{a^2 \alpha k}{(a^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}d\theta dz$

$= \dfrac{4\pi \alpha k h}{\sqrt{4a^2 + h^2}}$ where the substitution $z = a \tan(\theta)$ has been employed.

**The following are my misunderstandings:**

1. When doing the dot product $\mathbf{F} \mid_{r = a} \cdot \mathbf{n}$, shouldn't we be using $ a d\theta dz $ as the scaling factor for cylindrical coordinates instead of just $d\theta dz$?
2. As far as I can tell, $\mathbf{F} \mid_{r = a} \cdot \mathbf{n} \not = \dfrac{a^2 \alpha k}{(a^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}$? Where did the $\cos(\theta)$ go?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this solution.

Comment: You have the scaling factor "into" $\mathbf n$ as it is not unitary. And the dot product is correct: $a^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta=a^2$